# Двойные согласные в корне слов

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

**Будущая реформа русской орфографии**

Двойные согласные в корне слов, нужны ли они в нашем правописании? Приведу пример со словами *апелляция* и *инсталляция*. Двойное л в них практически не произносится и никакого особого смысла не прибавляет в написании. Во многих европейских языках используется одна согласная л/l :

инсталациjа (серб.)

iнсталяцiя (укр.)

instalacija (хорв.)

instalace (чеш.)

instalado (эспер.)

instalare (рум.)

instalacja (пол.)

инсталациjа (макед.)

innstalación (исп.)

iнсталяцыя (белор.)

instalazioa (баск.)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

apelio (валл.)

apelar (исп.)

apel (рум.)

апеловати (серб.)

апеляцiя (укр.)

apelacii (эспер.) и тд и тд ...

Можно взглянуть и на *фибрилляцию* :

**fibriliacija** (литов.)

В общем, вполне законно мы можем приравнять орфографию  вышеназванных слов к правописанию *ингаляции* и *реляции*, то есть не использовать лишние буквы там, где они не имеют никакого смысла. Вычеркнем исключения из наших словарей, облегчим жизнь сами себе.

(Полный списочек **лляций**, ровно дюжина :

апелляция,
дефибрилляция,
дистилляция,
инсталляция,
инстилляция,
интерпелляция,
констелляция,
осцилляция,
парцелляция,
пелляция,
сцинтилляция,
фибрилляция.

**Ляций** в десять раз больше - 123!)

Есть ли обоснованные возражения в грамотных источниках или у грамотных форумчан?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Об этом говорят многие учёные, в том числе Лопатин. Действительно,в русских словах сочетания двух одинаковых согласных обычно находятся между гласными на стыке приставки и корня, корня и суффикса. В иноязычных словах двойные согласные могут быть долгими и в корнях слов. Так как долгота звуков не свойственна фонематической системе русского языка, иноязычные слова, по мере их освоения русским языком, утрачивают долготу согласных и произносятся с одиночным звуком (то[н]ель, те[р]аса, а[п]арат, а[п]етит, ко[р]ектор, ко[м]ерция и т.п.).Почему бы их не писать с одним Н?
Двойной согласный обычно произносится в положении после ударного гласного (ср.: ва [нн]а, ма [сс]а, гру [пп]а, програ [мм]а и т.п.). На конце слова двойные согласные, как правило, не произносятся (ср. криста[л], мета[л], гри[п], гра[м] и т.п.).
Произношение двойных согласных как в русских словах, так и в иноязычных регламентировано в словарном порядке.Согласна, что когда у инояз. морфем нет русского аналога и входят в наш язык они как целый корень, от удвоенных согласных нужно решительно избавляться.Поэтому если слово ещё не закреплено в словаре — нужно писать его с одной согласной.Но как быть с теми словами, которые уже закреплены в словарях? Будет путаница, как с ЗОРЯНКОЙ-в одних словарях с -А-, в других с -О-.Зачем путать учеников, с которых требуют норму? Они только заучили словарные слова :аккомпанировать, аббревиатура, аппетит,тоннель, корректор, бюллетень,  грамматика, индифферентный, комментировать, баннер,- а их заставят переучивать? Уж если закрепились с одной -согласной, пусть пишутся с одной, хотя и в таких словах делают ошибки, некоторые пишут с двумя:балюстрада,алюминий, галерея, десерт, привилегия,импресарио, продюсер, тротуар, унисон и др.Значит, кому-то слышится долгий звук?

Не рекомендуется определять двойную согласную в заимствованном слове и путем сопоставления его со словом языка-оригинала, так как при ассимиляции иноязычной лексики вторая согласная в русском языке может утрачиваться:
агрегат (лат. aggregatus), адрес (фp. adresse), апартаменты (фр. appartement), апробация (лат. approbatio), атака (лат. attaque), атрибут (лат. attributum), афера (фр. affaire), афиша (фр. affiche), бизнес (англ. business) - поэтому бизнесмен, но: конгрессмен, кроссмен; буфер (англ. buffer), вернисаж (фр. vemissage), виньетка (фр. vignette), волейбол (англ. volleyball), галета (фр. galette), десерт (фр.dessert), канонада (фр. cannonade), офицер (нем.Offizier), пудинг (англ. pudding), ресурсы (фp. ressourees), тротуар (фр. trottoir).

Так что выход один: продолжать писать в соответствии с академическими словарями, а вновь входящие в язык писать с одной гласной.

Comment: Откуда эта псевдобоязнь переучивания? Введение будущих норм орфографии будет оговорено, допустим, пятилетним сроком, в течение которого разрешено использовать старые и новые формы. Мы учимся всю жизнь, и никто еще от нововведений не умер. С голоду умирают люди, а от новых упрощенных правил - нет. Академические словари **переписываются** с завидной скоростью, только шуба заворачивается, как говорится. Не бойтесь нового, оно все равно придет к вам в дом.

Comment: Это не псевдобоязнь, а опыт того, кто пытался учить грамотному письму школьников 33 года. Только научишь, появляются вот такие "переучиватели" ,и всё, чему учила, перечёркивается. Кому это надо? Вам дышать будет легче, если "грамматика"или "программа" будут писаться с одной М? А вот ошибок будет полно. Грамотный человек будет писать с двумя, потому что это закреплено во всех книгах, газетах, журналах, документах на протяжении десятков лет. Почему эти слова объявлять неправильно написанными? В угоду кому?Нужно УЧИТЬ, а не ПЕРЕучивать.

Comment: Я привел списочек **двенадцати** узкопрофессиональных слов, Вы заметили его? Вот о них покуда и идет речь, Людмила! Прошу обсудить именно их. Вы в школе эти слова тоже заучиваете?)

Волков бояться - в лес не ходить.

Comment: Апелляция, дефибрилляция, дистилляция,  парцелляция - термины, которые школьники учат и пишут, кстати, чаще грамотно, чем нет.Даже знают, что парцелла-часть. Оставьте их в покое.

Comment: Я, слава богу, никакими реформами не рулю и не собираюсь, так что упреков не принимаю))) А вот если представить себе учителя по любому предмету со столетним стажем, то горько такой педагог наплакался за свой век, это уж точно! 

"Реформы образования - в жизнь!"

Comment: Вот-вот, потому я против всяких реформ языка. Нужно УЧИТЬ те правила, что есть, а не придумывать новые.

Answer (score 3):

Если рассматривать суть проблемы, то согласен, двойные согласные в корне слова, действительно, как правило, не имеют смысла в русском языке. Мешает неопределённость с написанием удвоенных согласных? Безусловно. Сам был свидетелем неловкой ситуации, когда студентка (историк) на практике в школе попала в неудобную ситуацию, написав А**п**е**нн**ины не так как написано было в учебнике пятиклассников.  Почему же тогда не отменяют? На это есть две основных причины:

1. Традиционализм. Некоторые слова уже привыкли писать с двумя согласными, например *Россия*, и написание с одной выглядит почти кощунственным.
2. Экономические причины. Реформа орфографии - очень дорогое удовольствие, которое подразумевает под собой переиздание **всей** учебной литературы, в том числе и всех литературных произведений, входящих в программы школ и вузов. Как понимаете, это довольно  затратно.

Насколько реформирование орфографии трудозатратно, можно судить по реформе немецкого правописания, проходившей с 1996 по 2006 год. Реформа пережила уже три редакции и до сих пор не воспринимается обществом как единственная норма, подвергаясь немалой критике.

Comment: Никакого правила о написании таких слов нет, приходится 12 слов тупо запоминать. Если будет правило о написании всех слов (.....ляция) с одним л, то выучить его гораздо проще, чем зубрить исключения из общей практики. Упрощение правописания - дорогого стоит!

Comment: @Дерзкий, или @grumant (как правильней?), упрощать можно, только это дорого (обе причины мало зависят от количества изменений) и бессмысленно (если уж менять, то последовательно и кардинально, а не по частям).

Comment: Грумант отдыхает с 11 августа, Дерзкий на связи)))

Я же вам не академический институт и не МГУ!))) Кто мешает **последовательно и кардинально** улучшать русское правописание??? Мое предложение - одно из тысяч назревших изменений, а мне вы все начинаете реветь в голос : школьников жалко... учителей жалко... денег жалко... себя, любимых, жалко... Сидим на ресурсе по русскому языку и боимся слово молвить, как-то странно, коллеги. Сто лет назад по-другому писали? И через сто лет по-другому будут, не сомневайтесь. Давайте всерьез обсуждать предложения, а не отмахиваться обеими руками.

Comment: @Дерзкий, а что тут обсуждать? Имеет ли смысл отказаться от удвоенных согласных из вопроса? Да. Имеет ли смысл ради этого проводить реформу? Нет. Реформа орфографии и пунктуации безусловно зреет, но пока приходится писать по тем правилам, что есть.

Comment: Реформа как таковая - вообще не нужна. Достаточно повесить в сети сообщение от РАН : с понедельника разрешено вот такое написание, через три года оно будет единственно верным. Переделать учебную литературу **в интернете** - легко! Сейчас все школьники и студенты учатся именно при посредстве компов и ноутбуков. Не надо никаких реформ, достаточно простых и понятных изменений в соответствии с жизнью. Книги никто сейчас не читает, перепечатывать ничего не надо. Как в амерской конституции, достаточо опубликовать поправку к действующему основному закону. 

Именения произойдут в любом случае.

Comment: @Дерзкий, а вы в курсе, что по законам РФ, на решение суда нельзя подать апе**л**яцию, только апе**лл**яцию? Значит надо все законы и другие нормативно-правовые акты с этим словом переиздавать. Тоже самое касается и других слов. Любое реформирование письменного русского языка затрагивает всех россиян, поэтому удобство школьников и даже мнение РАН, тут на самом деле далеко не самое важное.

Comment: Еще и в тюрьму посодют за неправильную апеляцию, страх какой))) А давайте издадим закон о полном запрете всяких изменений в жизни! Чтобы все люди передохли, но изменяться никак не смели даже подумать. К запланированным маразмам нам не привыкать! Но рево**люция** после периода застоя - будет. И ВСЕ законы перепишут, бесплатно, из чистого энтузиазма))) И вместо гоу-моу вновь появятся школы!